# Copy an artifact from jenkins to another server with new name

Tags: java, copy, continuous-integration, jenkins, artifact

I have a few jobs that automatically build a java app. I would like it to automatically push it to a other server. I found a plugin that copies artifacts over ssh, but using it I end up with app-1.0-SNAPHSHOT.jar, app-1.1-SNAPHSHOT.jar and so on on the remote server.

I would like to have it as app.jar instead, overwriting the old one every time. Is there a "intelligent" way of doing this, or should I just make a shell script that looks for the newest one, and overwrites it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using a Maven project I would recommend [Mojo's Ship Maven Plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/ship-maven-plugin/) for doing the transfer via your build scripts.

If you want to do this via Jenkins plugins, there are the following plugin options:

- [Publish via SSH](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin)
- [Publish to a FTP server](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+FTP+Plugin)
- [Publish to a Windows file share](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+CIFS+Plugin)

Answer (score 1):

I just do it right in my build scripts. Why all the extra management? In ant,

```
<copy todir="${remote}"> 
    <globmapper from="*" to="app.jar"/>
    ...
</copy>
```

works perfectly fine.

Comment: Can you also rename it? My jobs are using maven, but I could set up another job...

Comment: @varesa That being the case, adding a shell command as a build step to do it would make the most sense to me.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I just wanted to know out of interest if there might have been some other way. I guess I'll just make a shell script which finds the latest version, extracts the plain name and copies it.